# Python Tkinter Mysql select statement returns curly braces around string

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, tkinter, curly-braces

I am dynamically populating button text in tkinter from values in a mysql database.

Single words are showing fine but strings with more than a single word are showing with curly brackets around them. I am not sure if it is because they are seen as a tuple or some other non string datatype.

I have a feeling it is the way Mysql stores the data but not sure how to handle it on the input or output to avoid this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the select query in Mysql. [Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T34v.png)

Here is the select statement:

```
def getChannelName(channel):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DBHost,
        user=Uname,
        passwd=Pword,
        database=Dbase
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    sql = "SELECT InputName FROM tbl_input WHERE tbl_input.InputChannel = '%s'" % (channel)
    mycursor.execute(sql) 
    r = mycursor.fetchone()
    mycursor.close()
    del mycursor
    return r
```

EDIT: I added print(r) just before "return r" to show values from the db. 
[image: SELECT query result]

This is where the select query is called from:

```
def initChannelNames(activeInputs):
# Read all the ADC channel names in a list 
    inputs = [0]*activeInputs
    for index in range(len(inputs)):
        inputs[index] = getChannelName(index)
    return inputs
```

This is where I use the data. I am creating buttons dynamically and using the queried data as button text.

```
inputs = initChannelNames(activeInputs)
#set the selectors
for index in range(len(inputs)):
    Button(selectorStackContainer, text=inputs[index], image=ledImg, width=Button_w, height=Button_h, command=callback, font=("Courier", 11), bg='grey', fg='black', compound = "left", anchor="w").grid(row=index, sticky="w")
```

And finally this is what is showing on the buttons:
[image: Output on the GUI]

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(r)` after the line `r = mycursor.fetchone()`

Comment: hint: mysql probably returns a list, not a single value.

Comment: @stovfl - I added the edit as requested.

Comment: @BryanOakley - do you mean that the purpose of fetchone() is to return multiple records?

Comment: @ChrisDuguid: No *curly braces*, let's verify before `Button(... text=inputs[index]`. Add `print(inputs[index])` before `Button(...`. PLEASE, NO IMAGES. What BryanOakley means is you could simplify the whole approach if you change to `SELECT ... WHERE TypeID=10 SORTED BY InputChannel` and use `return fetchall()`. Then use this `list` to define your `Button`'s.